# How to add a static JPEG into a Manipulate without slowing it down

Tags: manipulate, image

I´m trying to add an image from a book into a `Manipulate` but it makes the `Manipulate` update very, very slowly. So much so that it is not functional.

An little exammple is:

```
Manipulate[
  a = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
  Image[a, ImageSize -> 80]
  Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
      r*{Cos[u]*Sin[v], Cos[u]*Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]}]],
  {r, 3, 6}]
```

If the code concerned with the image is removed, the `Manipulate` has behaves well, but with the image code it behaves badly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
Manipulate[
 Row[{Image[a, ImageSize -> 80] , 
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[
     r*{Cos[u]*Sin[v], Cos[u]*Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 
      0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]}]]}], {r, 3, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Putting the `Import` in the `Manipulate` means that the image file has to be reloaded from disk every time you change `r`. And `Image[...] Show[...]` is a multiplication - I'm not sure if this makes it slower, but might trigger some error handling in the background.